# When to close a MySQL connection in Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am developing an application in Node.js with Express and MySQL. I have the following question, where I should close the connection to MySQL with the following code.

```
    iniciarSesion(correo_electronico, contrasena, ip){

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.db.query('CALL sp_iniciar_sesion( ?, ?, ?, @o_persona_id, @o_usuario_id, @o_nombre, @o_apellido, @o_privilegio, @o_estado, @o_mensaje)', [correo_electronico, contrasena, ip], (error, results, fields) => {
                if(error)
                    reject();
                else{
                    this.db.query('SELECT  @o_persona_id AS persona_id, @o_usuario_id AS usuario_id, @o_nombre AS nombre, @o_apellido AS apellido, @o_privilegio AS privilegio, @o_estado AS estado, @o_mensaje AS mensaje', (error, results, fields) => {
                        var resultadoFinal = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
                        if(resultadoFinal[0].estado === 0 || !resultadoFinal[0].estado)
                            reject();
                        else
                            resolve(resultadoFinal); 
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

In addition to this, this application is oriented to a large number of people using it at the same time, suppose that 1000 people at a time. Is there a way to optimize the code? or any suggestion?

Thank you.

**Update**

After a while I get the following error and the application closes:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
   at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
   at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/opencloud/sevenpickup/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
   at Protocol.emit (events.js:310:20)
   at Protocol._delegateError (/home/opencloud/sevenpickup/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
   at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/home/opencloud/sevenpickup/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:371:10)
   at Connection._handleNetworkError (/home/opencloud/sevenpickup/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
   at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
   at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
 errno: 'ECONNRESET',
 code: 'ECONNRESET',
 syscall: 'read',
 fatal: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should just open the connection once upon starting the application. This way you don't have to spend the extra time to reconnect for each query you make.

What you have now looks fine and you do not need to close the connection at all.

Comment: I have the following error after making a query. I Update the question

Comment: @GustavoGil That error simply means the SQL server is not running, or you are connecting to the wrong IP/host and port.

Comment: No, this error occurs after I make a query from the application and allow about 15 minutes to pass without doing anything.

Comment: @GustavoGil Which proves my point further? That's exactly what would happen if you were trying to connect to the wrong server, or the server was not running, or had some kind of bad configuration server side. Please post the code where you actually set up the connection.

Comment: My configuration for Connect to the server is fine. I execute a petition for my api. example: https://srv1.mydomain.com/api/endpoint. My server response 200 (ok) and one json Example: {json: true} from my method iniciarSesion. After a while, without making another request to the server, it gives that error. But the configuration of connection to the database server is fine. The problem is after execute a query.

Comment: @GustavoGil Then it sounds to me like you need to write a new question and properly describe this issue in more detail. I've already answered this particular question. Closing the connection is not necessary so your issue is somewhere else.